# Pearson correlation how do they calculate the average

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I have this table that represents the users and who they rate items
$$
\begin{array}{lrrrr}
\hline & I_{1} & I_{2} & I_{3} & I_{4} \\
\hline U_{1} & 4 & ? & 5 & 5 \\
U_{2} & 4 & 2 & 1 & \\
U_{3} & 3 & & 2 & 4 \\
U_{4} & 4 & 4 & & \\
U_{5} & 2 & 1 & 3 & 5 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

and I have this equation
$$
w_{u, v}=\frac{\sum_{i \in I}\left(r_{u, i}-\bar{r}_{u}\right)\left(r_{v, i}-\bar{r}_{v}\right)}{\sqrt{\sum_{i \in I}\left(r_{u, i}-\bar{r}_{u}\right)^{2}} \sqrt{\sum_{i \in I}\left(r_{v, i}-\bar{r}_{v}\right)^{2}}}
$$

it is written also

> where the $i \in I$ summations are over the items that both the users $u$ and $v$ have rated and $\bar{r}_{u}$ is the average rating of the co-rated items of the $u$ th user. In an example in Table 4, we have $w_{1,5}=0.756$.

My question is how do they calculate the $\bar{r}_{u}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the text you attached says, $\bar r_{u} $ refers to the average of the co-rated items of user u, (items rated by both users we are interested in). Define $I$ as the set of items that have been rated by both $u$ and $v$ and find $$\bar r_{u} = 1 / |I| * \sum_{i \in I}{r_{u,i}} $$

In the case of $w_{1,5}$, we would have
$$ I = \{1,3,4\}$$
And for the relevant averages
 $$\bar r_{1} = 1/3 * (4 + 5 + 5)$$
and
$$\bar r_{5} = 1/3 * (2 + 3 +5)$$

Comment: where did you get `1/3` from?

Comment: Raters 1 and 5 have co-rated items 1,3, and 4, so 3 items in total. And then you compute the average of those ratings. As an example, if you were interested in raters 4, and 5, the co-rated items would be 1 and 2, and you would have 1/2 as the coefficient in the equation.